# mathematical induction on product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M_1,\dots, M_k (k\geqslant2)$ be matrices and their orders may not be the same.

However, $M_1M_2\cdots M_k$ is a product of matrices which is a well defined square matrix.

Prove that $M_iM_{i+1}\cdots M_kM_1M_2\cdots M_{i-1}$is also a well defined square matrix for $2 \leqslant i \leqslant k$. And hence prove that $trace(M_1M_2\cdots M_k)=trace(M_iM_{i+1}\cdots M_kM_1M_2\cdots M_{i-1})$.

I know I should start with mathematical induction on $i$ but I am confused about how to do with $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this requires induction. If $M_1M_2\cdots M_k$ is square and defined, it is easy to see that, their orders must be
$$n_1\times n_2$$
$$n_2\times n_3$$
$$n_3 \times n_4$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n_k\times n_1$$

From here it is obvious that "shifting" any $i$ matrices to the bottom of the list would still preserve the transitivity(is that the proper term?) of the ordered pairs $\{(n_1',n_2'),(n_2',n_3'),\cdots(n_k',n_1')\}$

Comment: Anything that has $\color{blue}\ldots$ in the middle requires induction.

Comment: @GitGud then I showed him *what* to induce, didn't I? the number of rows for the $i^{th}$ matrix = number of columns for $(i+1)^{th}$ matrix.

Comment: Proceed with the usual induction. Although why would you say *anything* that had $\dots$ requires induction? Does this? $$s=1+2+3+\cdots+n$$ $$s=n+n-1+n-2+\cdots+1$$ $$2s=n(n+1)$$ but then again, you might be talking about absolute rigor here.

Comment: The symbol $1+2+3+\ldots +n$ only has meaning if interpreted as $\sum \limits_{k=0}^n(k)$ and similarly $n+(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots +1$ is just $\sum \limits_{k=0}^n(n-k)$. So you get $2s=\sum \limits_{k=0}^n(k+n-k)=n\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (1)=n(n+1)$, and it seems like you got away from using induction (apart for it being needed to prove the summation identities), but how do you prove that $s=\sum \limits_{k=0}^n(n-k)$? Maybe I'm talking about absolute rigor, yes. But I just had to leave that comment.

Comment: @GitGud I never said that I had an *objection* with anyone talking about absolute rigor, I just said I prefer not to involve myself in that kind of work. It isn't needed here, we are neither dealing with divergent sums, nor infinite series,(I am referring to the addition example) but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Yes, anything that requires $...$ or $\sum_{k=1}^n$ or $\prod_{k=1}^n$ requires induction at some level. But with clever tricks one may reduce it to basic facts like $\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k+b_k)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$. Which, if one really wants to prove them, will require the recursive definition of the sum symbol and induction based on this recursive definition. -- But here it is sufficient to set $A=M_1...M_{i-1}$ and $B=M_i...M_k$ and confirm that (the dimensions match and) $trace(AB)=trace(BA)$.

Comment: @LutzL I believe I said that in form, didn't I?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: In principle, yes, the first part is, after reading the other comments again, redundant. I was just hung up on the interpretation of "not needed".

Comment: @LutzL oh loose wording on my part.

Comment: @draks... Well noticed :P